# Raspberry Pi 4 wifi intermittent latency drop

Tags: wifi, power-supply, battery

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 headless on a Raspberry Pi 3 and 4. SSH connection is through a wireless router with only my laptop and the Pi connected. Pinging the Pi (192.168.0.215) shows the connection drops every 10 seconds or so. I cannot figure out why. The Raspberry Pi is powered by a [5V battery pack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09HXYTDMV).

```
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe55:f018  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:55:f0:18  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 603452  bytes 834673875 (834.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 347262  bytes 21531641 (21.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1239552  bytes 276796686 (276.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1239552  bytes 276796686 (276.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.215  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::361d:ecbe:7ed9:d11f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:00:a5:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 67732  bytes 4043914 (4.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 227659  bytes 291814478 (291.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7c:dd:90:62:32:16  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here are some ping results

```
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=3273ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=548ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=1116ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=2217ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=76ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=66ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.215: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=64
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that pairing a PS4 gamepad vai bluetooth and running the driver program ds4drv cause the pings to drop intermittently. I guess the cause is ds4drv interfers with any wifi signal, either on board or external dongle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).